# Linq sub collection criteria where collection is a list of doubles

Tags: linq, collections

If I have a couple of classes like this ;

```
    public class Employee
    {
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public string Address { get; set; }
         public double Salary { get; set; }
         public List<Salary> PastSalaries { get; set; }
    }

    public class Salary
    {
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

I can get a list of employees who have had a past salary that was less than a certain amount ; eg

```
var employees = employeeList.Where(o => o.PastSalaries.Any(p => p.Amount < 35000));
```

this works fine, but if my past salaries collection wasn't a collection of Salary classes but rather a collection of doubles. eg

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    **public List<double> PastSalaries { get; set; }**
}
```

then how can i do the same query as before?

```
var employees = employeeList.Where(o => o.PastSalaries.Any(???? < 35000));
```

What do I do my comparison against?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var employees = employeeList.Where(o => o.PastSalaries.Any(p => p < 35000));
```

The parameter to the delegate is now a double, not a `Salary` type with an `Amount` property, so you can compare on the parameter directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var employees = employeeList.Where(o => o.PastSalaries.Any(p=>p < 35000));
```

Try this. In first case your type is `Salary` and you check `Amount` field of that type.
In this case you want to check `double` value ,so p<`35000` will work properly.